# importing search_targetpixelfile from lightkurve causes segmentation fault/kernel crash

Tags: python

I've just started trying to get to grips with using lightkurve, initially working out of vim I was having any attempt at importing lightkurve cause a 'Segmentation Fault: 11' and, when switching workspace to Jupyter Notebook, this same code caused a crash in the kernel. I really don't know how to go about solving this..

```
from lightkurve import search_targetpixelfile

pixelfile = search_targetpixelfile("KIC 8462852", quarter=16).download(quality_bitmask='hardest');
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. Python modules generally don't cause segmentation faults. Rather, they should raise exceptions. If a module causes a segfault, it means that it's written in something other than Python, so it probably can't be solved with Python. It may be a good idea to message the devs about this bug.

Comment: That'd be awkward, the code comes from their [quickstart](https://docs.lightkurve.org/quickstart.html) section on how to use the library. Will chase this up and post anything more I find out here.